# How to add rank to mysql scoreboard table?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a football ranking scoreboard. I got an sql script that works perfectly, but I just can't figure out ranking. I researched all the threads here on Stack Overflow and nothing works for me. I figured out how to add rank to SQL code but when it comes to displaying the ranks it gives me syntax error.

Here's the code so far:

```
select 
@rank := @rank + 1 as rank,
ekipa, 
count(case when scoreHome is not null then 1 end) P, 
count(case when scoreHome > scoreAway then 1 end) W, 
count(case when scoreAway > scoreHome then 1 end) L, 
count(case when scoreHome = scoreAway then 1 end) D, 
sum(scoreHome) GS, 
sum(scoreAway) GA, 
sum(scoreHome) - sum(scoreAway) GD,
sum(
      case when scoreHome > scoreAway then 3 else 0 end 
    + case when scoreHome = scoreAway then 1 else 0 end
) PTS 
from (
    select home ekipa, scoreHome, scoreAway from futliga_pc_liga1 
  union all
    select away, scoreAway, scoreHome from futliga_pc_liga1
) a 
group by ekipa
order by PTS desc, GD desc
```

So I tried putting the

```
    select @rank := 0
```

to the end of a script as I saw it working on other peoples scripts but it gives me syntax error. This script as you see it it works perfectly just the rank column is NULL.

So what would be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

**Changed Answer**

change it to:

```
SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, results.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
    ekipa, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN scoreHome IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) P, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN scoreHome > scoreAway THEN 1 END) W, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN scoreAway > scoreHome THEN 1 END) L, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN scoreHome = scoreAway THEN 1 END) D, 
    SUM(scoreHome) GS, 
    SUM(scoreAway) GA, 
    SUM(scoreHome) - SUM(scoreAway) GD,
    SUM(
          CASE WHEN scoreHome > scoreAway THEN 3 ELSE 0 END 
        + CASE WHEN scoreHome = scoreAway THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) PTS 
    FROM (
        SELECT home ekipa, scoreHome, scoreAway FROM futliga_pc_liga1 
      UNION ALL
        SELECT away, scoreAway, scoreHome FROM futliga_pc_liga1
    ) a 
    GROUP BY ekipa
    ORDER BY PTS DESC, GD DESC
) AS results
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) AS parameter;
```

**test**

```
MariaDB [bb]> SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, results.*
    -> FROM (
    ->     SELECT
    ->     ekipa,
    ->     COUNT(CASE WHEN scoreHome IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) P,
    ->     COUNT(CASE WHEN scoreHome > scoreAway THEN 1 END) W,
    ->     COUNT(CASE WHEN scoreAway > scoreHome THEN 1 END) L,
    ->     COUNT(CASE WHEN scoreHome = scoreAway THEN 1 END) D,
    ->     SUM(scoreHome) GS,
    ->     SUM(scoreAway) GA,
    ->     SUM(scoreHome) - SUM(scoreAway) GD,
    ->     SUM(
    ->           CASE WHEN scoreHome > scoreAway THEN 3 ELSE 0 END
    ->         + CASE WHEN scoreHome = scoreAway THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ->     ) PTS
    ->     FROM (
    ->         SELECT home ekipa, scoreHome, scoreAway FROM futliga_pc_liga1
    ->       UNION ALL
    ->         SELECT away, scoreAway, scoreHome FROM futliga_pc_liga1
    ->     ) a
    ->     GROUP BY ekipa
    ->     ORDER BY PTS DESC, GD DESC
    -> ) AS results
    -> CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) AS parameter;
+------+-----------------------+---+---+---+---+------+------+------+------+
| rank | ekipa                 | P | W | L | D | GS   | GA   | GD   | PTS  |
+------+-----------------------+---+---+---+---+------+------+------+------+
|    1 | PSG (Krasoticnik)     | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |    3 |    1 |    2 |    3 |
|    2 | Tottenham (cuha93)    | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |    3 |    2 |    1 |    3 |
|    3 | FC Barcelona (zlabra) | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |    2 |    3 |   -1 |    0 |
|    4 | Liverpool (Jeraj99)   | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |    1 |    3 |   -2 |    0 |
+------+-----------------------+---+---+---+---+------+------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [bb]>
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not right it prints me all sorts of numbers and not 1, 2, 3, etc. in order

Comment: @ago - i have seen and change my answer

Comment: nope still doesn't work now it tells me that there is a syntax error in line 1

Comment: @janip - you must put the tablename before the star : SELECT ...., results.* - if have changed the answer

Comment: Hmm I tried and still syntax error so I must make it: table_name.* OR results.table_name?

Comment: can you post some data on sqlfiddle to check it

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0988d2/1   Here you go EDIT: it's just two entries in the table

Comment: @janip - now it works, puh hard work. please try it from my answer

Comment: YES it works! :) Thank you very much for your help :)